# Mongodb/Mongoose: how to group by field adding incrementing number?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have simple table with a String field 'host'. And I want to query structure for cyclic iteration through elements without repetition of same host. So instead of iterating like this: "a3, a3, a3, a1, a1, a2", we will have "a3, a1, a2, a3, a1, a3".

Example:

```
{ host: "a3" }, { host: "a3" }, { host: "a3" }, { host: "a1" }, { host: "a1" }, { host: "a2" }
```

So far I am thinking to group them by host and also have increasing index in every group:

```
{ host: "a3", i: 0 }, { host: "a3", i: 1 }, { host: "a3", i: 2 }, { host: "a1", i: 0 }, { host: "a1", i: 1 }, { host: "a2", i: 0 }
```

And after sorting by i:

```
{ host: "a3", i: 0 }, { host: "a1", i: 0 }, { host: "a2", i: 0 },  { host: "a3", i: 1 }, { host: "a1", i: 1 }, { host: "a3", i: 2 }
```

I have no idea how to make this query with Mongoose. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you'll need an **aggregation** consisting  to use `$group` stage followed by `$project` to retrieve identical structure as you have described (for example: `{ host: 'a3', i: 0 }`

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$host',
      i: {
          $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      host: '$_id',
      i: '$i'
    }
  }
]
```

`$group` will be used to group same hosts together while `$project` will reshape documents to match your desired structure (instead of leaving `_id`).

Comment: Hi. Thx for your reply. I think this solution does two things wrong. 1) Final number of elements should be same as initial. When we grouping by host, it reduced to uniques. 2) 'i' here is sum of same 'host' elements in each group. It needs to be the increasing index in every group of hosts.

Comment: @RealNmae I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve then. Can you provide more examples or wider explanation? :)

Comment: I need to make endpoint which will return one game at a time. And if user keep pushing on "look again" button, he will receive another game. This will return games cyclically. But I want to avoid returning two consequent games of same host. So a sequence of "g1,g1,g2,g2,g3" I would like to be returned as "g1,g2,g3,g1,g2". Another example: "g1,g1,g2,g1,g1", the returned sequence will be "g1,g2,g1,g2,g1..."

Comment: This looks easier to implement using code itself instead of at database level. Not sure how to implement such ordering, I also misunderstood your question earlier.